# Portable server room air-con options

Tags: server-room, physical-environment

We are looking for portable industrial air conditioners for our server room which whould blow hot air to the ceiling cavity, split-system is not an option.

Something exactly like this would be ideal, but unfortunately not available in AUS:

- http://www.apc.com/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=ACPA4000&ISOCountrycode=us
- [www.apcmedia.com/salestools/ASTE-6Z2RUU_R1_EN.pdf](http://www.apcmedia.com/salestools/ASTE-6Z2RUU_R1_EN.pdf)

So we're pretty much looking for competing products to the APC's NetworkAIR PA4000 available in Australia?

We currently have 3 x [DeLonghi Pinguino PACT120](http://www.delonghi.com.au/media/pdf/PACT120ECO.pdf), but space is limited and getting more of these is probably not ideal.

[alt text http://www.ikoo.com.au/Aircond.png](http://www.ikoo.com.au/Aircond.png)

Comment: When faced with such a need we contacted the company that services our aircons, who were able to supply a list of sources, including themselves. Give your service company a call.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like those guys can hire you some serious industrial portable air conditioners suitable for use in server rooms. And they are in Australia:

- [Active Air](http://www.activeair.com.au/air-conditioning-conditioner-hire-rental-rent-portable/portable-air-conditioners/ac-061/2/35)
- [Air Power](http://www.airpowerclimatehire.com.au/airconditioning.html)

Those are hiring and selling them (second hand?):

- [Phd Rentals](http://www.phdrentals.com.au/industrial-air-conditioner-hire.html)

Those are selling:

- [Blackwoods](http://www2.blackwoods.com.au/infoBANKProduct.aspx?SG=2000165&S=4084728&G=2003688&P=2025485)

It looks like you need to call them to find out the prices.